# Unable to add credit card in Google Wallet

Tags: google-play-store, google-wallet

Whenever I try and buy an app, google asks me to add a credit card in google wallet. But when I finish adding me credit card details, phone number and address and do save (I'm using my sony xperia mobile for this btw) I get an error saying:

```
Error:
Error while retrieving information from server. [RPS:S-7:AEC-0]
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Just for tests, did you try to buy via web?

Comment: i cant add it via web either, if thats what you're asking

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Now the RBI has given instruction to all banks to make changes in the server to give the transaction password while doing net purchase. there is no option in google wallet to put transaction password.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer and be a bit more verbose? i find it hard to understand